# Spaceline color issue

Tags: init-file, spaceline

so the problem I am having is that my spaceline plugin will have little squares of miss color until I do powerline-reset. (Just like the github issue.) Problem is that I am having to do this every time I start up emacs. Is there a way to make it so I don't have to do this every time I start up emacs?

Here is the issue on github: https://github.com/TheBB/spaceline/issues/11

```
(use-package spaceline
 :ensure t
 :init
 (progn
  (require 'spaceline-config)
  (setq powerline-default-separator 'wave)
  (setq spaceline-workspace-numbers-unicode t)
  (setq spaceline-separator-dir-left '(left . left))
  (setq spaceline-separator-dir-right '(right . right))
  (setq powerline-height 20)
  (setq spaceline-highlight-face-func 'spaceline-highlight-face-evil-state)
  (spaceline-toggle-major-mode-on)
  (spaceline-toggle-minor-modes-off)
  (spaceline-toggle-battery-on)
  (spaceline-toggle-hud-off)
  (spaceline-spacemacs-theme)))
```

Answer (score 1):

You should call `(powerline-reset)` as the last entry in your `use-package` config for spaceline. So it should look something like this:

```el
(use-package spaceline
:ensure t
:init 
(progn 
  ;; size of modeline
  (setq powerline-height 18)
  (setq spaceline-highlight-face-func 'spaceline-highlight-face-evil-state)

  ;; slant (requires srbg support)
  (setq-default powerline-default-separator 'slant) 
  (setq spaceline-separator-dir-left '(right . right))
  (setq spaceline-separator-dir-right '(right . right))
 )
:config
(require 'spaceline-config)
(spaceline-toggle-buffer-size-off)
(spaceline-spacemacs-theme)
(setq spaceline-buffer-encoding-abbrev-p nil
      spaceline-window-numbers-unicode t
      spaceline-line-column-p nil
      spaceline-buffer-id-p nil
      spaceline-minor-modes-separator nil)
      (powerline-reset)
 )
```

Comment: This actually doesn't work. It is so weird. I don't get why I have to manually run this command :( I do appreciate your trying.

Comment: hmmm...have you tried separating things into `init` and `config` sections? I'm wondering if something is getting called that is interfering with `(powerline-reset)`.